# x264 IDR access unit with a SPS and a PPS

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, h.264, x264

I am trying to encode video in h.264 that when split with Apples HTTP Live Streaming tools media file segmenter will pass the media file validator I am getting two errors on the split MPEG-TS file

```
WARNING: Media segment contains a video track but does not contain any IDR access unit with a SPS and a PPS.
WARNING: 7 samples (17.073 %) do not have timestamps in track 257 (avc1).
```

After hours of research I think the "IDR" warning relates to not having keyframes in the right place on the segmented MPEG-TS file so in my ffmpeg command I set -keyint_min 1 to ensure keyframes where at every frame, but this didn't work.

Although it would be great to get an answer, if anyone can shed any light on what a "IDR access unit with a SPS and a PPS" is or what the timestamps warning means I would be very grateful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix can be found on this thread https://devforums.apple.com/thread/45830?tstart=15

Comment: Can you tell us what the fix is?