# My app rejected for fourth time because i don't meet HTTP live streaming protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, http-streaming

This is my apple rejection 
[image]

also screen shoot of my test using mediastreamvalidatortool is
[image]

So what can i do at server side to make this stream accepted by Apple?
This app is for iPhone3gs/iPad1,2 also iPhone4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW5
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming
[x264 IDR access unit with a SPS and a PPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613974/x264-idr-access-unit-with-a-sps-and-a-pps)
https://devforums.apple.com/thread/45830?tstart=15  (requires apple ID with developer account)
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH1-DontLinkElementID_39

You have to modify your serverside to provide HTTP Live streaming protocol and modify your media via recoding

Other suggested solutions are:

- instead of making a transport stream, make a .mov file and pass that into mediafilesegmenter
- use mediastreamsegmenter instead of medafilesegmenter for your transport stream file (cat  | mediastreamsegmenter -p)

Comment: i don't own the server but i need to send specific points to the man responsible for the server to make this link accepted by apple i may post you the link to test it and see what exactly issues i have in this .m3u8 file

Comment: sorry, but I'm not able to debug it in the moment, better to post him documentation about how the server-side should work and let him to fix it for you

Comment: Ok does the link you support me meet all requirement i need to approve my iPhone/iPad app..

Comment: yes, afaik it's official development guide, so it should provide everything you need. I added one link to make sure it is complete.

Comment: i have send him the docs but he need to know how to fix it...to make it as you work per your links..if you can support me with requirement in points for one link to meet the requirements by apple..but remember that the link should meet iPhone4,iPhone3gs,iPad also